# Visual Studio 2022 showing all requests and responses in a .Net core web app server in output window

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, visual-studio-2022

Visual studio 2022 recently (possibly after an update, or git commit - but probably not, read below) started showing all the http info reqs/responses, in the "[Project] - ASP.NET Core Web Server" output window, causing the text to scroll so fast it makes it impossible to debug anything and find even fatal exceptions (without stopping my application every time):

[image]

I have the same git project + branch loaded on my work machine with exactly the same launch params in my properties/launchSettings.json file and this doesn't happen on my work machine.

I have checked all the possible recent git commits which could have affected the logging but there has been no recent changes which indicate this being the case

My thought are some obscure setting in VS2022 that I have accidentally changed/or in an update?

Any help I appreciate, thank you.

**EDIT: These output messages do not display at all on a different machine**

**EDIT 2: I exported my VS settings from work -> home PC and this is still an issue**

Comment: May be you are using a Faster machine and/or one with faster ethernet interface.

Comment: @jdweng both have 16T CPUs + the .net app is locally hosted so ethernet interfaces wouldn't matter - I don't think a HW difference causes an issue with the debug window but it's entirely possible vs22 might be implementing some different debugging level automatically based on hw specs but it's very unlikely

Comment: I didn't just mean hardware when I said "faster ethernet interface".  You work network probably has more uses resulting in slower throughput as well as virus checkers and firewall.

Comment: @jdweng When I say locally hosted I mean local to the machine i.e. localhost. There will be no networking overhead associated that could influence the dotnet sw or visual studio.

Comment: What happens if you take the laptop home?  localhost still may be slowed down by virus checkers, firewall.